# How to install symfony project with docker?

Tags: docker, symfony

In docs there is one of commands to install:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton my_project_name
```

I have condigured docker with php.

Trying to run

```
docker-compose exec php composer create-project symfony/skeleton harbors
```

And it installs subdirectory harbors in my directory.

Ok, then if I want to not create subdirectory, I try:

```
cd ..
docker-compose exec php composer create-project symfony/skeleton harbors
```

It then gives error

ERROR:
Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
parent. Are you in the right directory?
Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml

Then try going back to my directory and do this:

```
docker-compose exec php composer create-project symfony/skeleton ../harbors
```

Then it installs in wrong place again - I cannot even see files. But when I entered in docker php conttainer, I could see them when going up one directory.

Tried also getting into docker container and execute:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton my_project_name
```

Still it install in subfolder my_project_name.

Could maybe move files after installing but that does not look correct way. So what is the correct way with docker?

Comment: I know it's prob not the right way but I always install it to the subfolder and just move all the files up a level once installed

Comment: How is this related to Docker? What keeps you from moving the files after the installation?

Comment: Ok I moved but this looks like somethinig I am doing wrong and me being angry than I cannot find right way. Right way I imagine files are installed straigth to where they have to be. How it is related - because I am using docker command.